# How to remove a sub-node that is 2-level down from the top node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below XML and I just want to remove the sub-node CstmrCdtTrfInitn / PmtInf/ Dbtr/ Id and keep the other nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>...</GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
        <PmtInfId>PInfId20180824a</PmtInfId>
        <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
        <PmtTpInf>...</PmtTpInf>
        <ReqdExctnDt>2018-08-24</ReqdExctnDt>
        <Dbtr>
            <Nm>ABC US Company</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>...</PstlAdr>
            <Id>
                <OrgId>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>222222222</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </OrgId>
            </Id>
        </Dbtr>
        <DbtrAcct>...</DbtrAcct>
        <DbtrAgt>...</DbtrAgt>
        <CdtTrfTxInf>...</CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

I have below XSL and yes I know xsl:template must be top-level but hopefully can explain what I'm trying to do. What's the best way to do it with XSLT? Thanks.

Below XSL tries to move the ID value from node /Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/Id/OrgId/Othr/Id to the header node /Document/CstmrCdtTrfInitn/GrpHdr/InitgPty/Id/OrgId/Othr/Id. After that remove the whole node under "CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/Id/OrgId/Othr/Id"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:template match="wpc:Document/wpc:CstmrCdtTrfInitn">
        <CstmrCdtTrfInitn>            
            <xsl:variable name="ach_id" select="wpc:PmtInf/wpc:Dbtr/wpc:Id/wpc:OrgId/wpc:Othr/wpc:Id"/>            
            <xsl:for-each select="wpc:GrpHdr">
                <GrpHdr>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wpc:MsgId"/>
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="wpc:InitgPty">
                        <InitgPty>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="wpc:Nm"/>   
                              <Id>
                               <OrgId>
                                 <Othr>
                                   <Id><xsl:value-of select="$ach_id"/></Id>
                                 </Othr>
                              </OrgId>
                            </Id>  
                        </InitgPty>   
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </GrpHdr>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="wpc:PmtInf">
                <!-- How to do below correctly to just clear PmtInf/Dbtr/Id block? -->
                <!-- 
            <<xsl:template match="wpc:Dbtr">
                <Dbtr>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wpc:Nm"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="wpc:PstlAdr"/>
                </Dbtr>
            </xsl:template> -->

                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>            
            </xsl:for-each>  
        </CstmrCdtTrfInitn>                           
    </xsl:template>          

    <!--All other nodes remain unchanged in output-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wpc:Document/wpc:CstmrCdtTrfInitn/wpc:PmtInf/wpc:Dbtr/wpc:Id"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using the *identity template* in combination with an empty template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- Empty template that ignores the specified elements -->
    <xsl:template match="CstmrCdtTrfInitn/PmtInf/Dbtr/Id"/>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
    <GrpHdr>...</GrpHdr>
    <PmtInf>
        <PmtInfId>PInfId20180824a</PmtInfId>
        <PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
        <PmtTpInf>...</PmtTpInf>
        <ReqdExctnDt>2018-08-24</ReqdExctnDt>
        <Dbtr>
            <Nm>ABC US Company</Nm>
            <PstlAdr>...</PstlAdr>

        </Dbtr>
        <DbtrAcct>...</DbtrAcct>
        <DbtrAgt>...</DbtrAgt>
        <CdtTrfTxInf>...</CdtTrfTxInf>
    </PmtInf>
</CstmrCdtTrfInitn>
```

To remove the empty line from the output, add the following top-level element:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```